# Unable to use native javascript Array functions in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, cordova

I've got to the point where I have started using `Array` functions inside of my Phonegap app.

I am running `KickCat 4.4.2` with my Nexus 5, my Nexus 4 also suffers from the same problem.

But to my shock horror it seems that which ever browser phonegap is using it does not have any of the array functions defined.

```
Array()
 []
Array.reverse
 undefined
Array.join
 undefined
Array.push
 undefined
```

So `Array` is a function, but anything more does not exist.

Is there anyway to active or use these functions?

The actual function I'm after is `Array.reverse`.

Comment: `Array` instances inherit their methods from [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) rather than the `Array` constructor itself. You should find `Array.prototype.reverse`, `Array.prototype.join`, etc. to exist.

Comment: Fantastic @JonathanLonowski. So browsers have just packaged this up nicely for us? But whichever browser is being used to display the phonegap app's does not.

Comment: PhoneGap should be using the native web views for each platform, which I believe are using Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android. But, my point is that you're looking for the methods on the wrong object. `Array.reverse` shouldn't exist, but `Array.prototype.reverse` should.

Comment: KickCat sounds like a very violent OS.

Comment: I'm always of the persuasion that adding a lil humor can only improve ones life. Kicking that cat always helps. @JonathanLonowski My bad. However I only used this way of checking after I got the error trying to use the function Array.reverse. `Uncaught TypeError: Object function Array() {[native code]} has no method 'reverse'` when running `Array.reverse(Object.keys(data))` Maybe I have misunderstood the problem, but I assumed that Array wasn't available. But as you say: `Array.prototype.push
function push() { [native code] }` does indeed exist. I am looping through an object. `for` is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object function Array() {[native code]} has no method 'reverse'` when running `Array.reverse(Object.keys(data))`

If you'd like to reverse the collection returned by `Object.keys()`, the collection will be an `Array` so you can simply chain the call to `.reverse()`:

```
var reversedKeys = Object.keys(data).reverse();
```

---

The error is because `Array.reverse()` doesn't exist and typically won't. The standard `Array` methods are actually defined as [properties of `Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods) rather than as [properties of `Array` itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods).

Though, you can define it so it's available from both:

```
Array.reverse = function (collection) {
    return Array.prototype.reverse.call(collection);
};

var reversedKeys = Array.reverse(Object.keys(data));
```

Comment: One day I want to be more like you Jona... Hopefully not to long though please?